# I need to replace non-ASCII characters in pandas data frame column in python 2.7

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

This question was asked many times, but non of the solutions worked for me.

The data frame was pulled from a third party excel file with 'UTF-8' encoding:

```
pd.read_excel(file, encoding = 'UTF-8', sheet_name = worksheet)
```

But I still have characters like " â€™ " instead of " ' " in some lines.

On the top of the code I have the following

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
```

The following line does not throw errors, but do not change anything in the data:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str.replace("â€™","'")
```

I tried with dictionary (which has the same core), like

```
    repl_dict = {"â€™": "'"}
    for k,v in repl_dict.items():
        df.loc[df.text.str.contains(k), 'text'] = 
        df.text.str.replace(pat=k,repl=v)
```

and tried many other approaches including regex, but nothing worked.

When I tried:

```
def replace_apostrophy(text):
    return text.replace("â€™","'")
df['text'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: replace_apostrophy(x))
```

I received the following error - 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

When I tried:

```
df["text"] = df["text"].apply(lambda text: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text))
```

I got the following error - 
TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be unicode, not float

The text has also emojis that afterwords I need to count somehow.

Can someone give me a good advice?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you sure the encoding is UTF-8?

Comment: This looks like a "Windows 1252" encoding.

Comment: I agree, but that was the data I got in Excel. I tried        pd.read_excel(file, encoding = 'cp1252', sheet_name = worksheet) Did not see any difference.

Comment: Looks like the original file has a mix of encodings as I see " ' " and  " â€™ " in different rows.

Comment: is it possible to contact the third party? It looks like something is wrong with generating the file. Perhaps they have set their database (or other datasource) to a different encoding than that in which they generate the file, hence the two introduce data in two different encodings. It might be better to fix the problem "*upstream*", then to aim to fix the endproduct, since then there can be "data loss".

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution myself. It might look clumsy, but works perfectly in my case:

```
    df["text"] = df["text"].apply(lambda text: unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text).encode('ascii','backslashreplace'))
```

I had to replace nan values prior to run that code.

That operation gives me ascii symbols only that can be easily replaced:

```
    def replace_apostrophy(text):
return text.replace("a\u0302\u20acTM","'")
```

Hope this would help someone.